# Using a nested array within a find method

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to find a way to do a find in cakePHP based on an array I have received from another find.

Structure: I have a number of sites in my database. I also have a number of businesses. Each business hasOne site, but not all sites belong to a business. I am trying to get a list of all orders in a sale that go to a site that belongs to a business. I have already done a find method to get all the sites that belong to a business, which gets returned in a nested array ($businesses) which looks like this:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Business' => array(
        'id' => '17',
        'name' => 'Name',
        'code' => 'Code',
        'discount' => 'Discount',
        'site_id' => 47
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'Business' => array(
        'id' => '19',
        'name' => 'Name',
        'code' => 'Code',
        'discount' => 'Discount',
        'site_id' => '108'
    )
),
```

Now, I want to use the data in this array as part of another find method. Something like this:

```
$this->Order->find('all', array(
            'contain'=>array("Info"),
            'conditions'=>array('Order.sale_id' => $sale, 'Order.site_id' => $businesses),
            'order'=> array('last_name' => 'ASC')));
```

The problem is that when I do it this way, I get an Array to string conversion error because $businesses is a nested array, so Cake converts this to

```
AND `Order`.`site_id` IN (Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array)
```

How do I access the nested arrays so that I can compare the site_id on the order to the site_id of each business in my array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need all that information returned from `find()` to run your next query.

What you basically need is SQL's `IN` expression and an array of IDs which should be put as something like:

```
$this->Order->find('all', array(
    'conditions'=>array(
        'Order.site_id' => Hash::extract($businesses, '{n}.Business.site_id')
     )
));
```

[`Hash::extract()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash%3a%3aextract) will create an array of the ids contained in the supplied path `{n}.Business.site_id` of `$businesses` and cakephp will notice that you have an array there so it will create an SQL's `IN` expression to tell your database that you want the id to be one of those given.

You should make your previous finds return only what you need (i.e. ids and primary keys) in order to reduce the burden on the DB.

Comment: You don't need to specify `IN` with Cake, if your comparison is an array it assume it.

Comment: Now it's returning an empty array.

As for the previous find, I used that find in another method. I just passed the result to this function since it had the information I needed.

Comment: If you need it keep it :)
If you don't get any results it means there are no data matching the conditions. Check if your conditions are right or not and if the produced SQL is what you're aiming for. But the general idea is what I have in my answer.

Comment: Belay that last comment. I was searching for two conditions that didn't coincide in the range I was checking. This worked great. Thank you!